# Is there an alternative to UPDLOCK with NOWAIT that leaves the transaction committable?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, transactions, locking

Given the following:

DB objects in SQL Server:

```sql
create table t (c int);

create table t2 (c int);

create table t3 (c int);

create table t4 (c int);

create trigger tr on t after update as begin
  update t2 set c = c;
end;

create trigger tr2 on t2 after update as begin
  begin try
    insert into t4 values (1);
    select null from t3 with (updlock, nowait);
  end try
  begin catch
    -- How to recover if t3 can't be locked?
  end catch;
end;
```

Java programs running simultaneously:

1. P1 that locks `t3` in the same manner as in `tr2` above but does not give up the lock until terminated.
2. P2 that updates `t`.

P2 appears to fail silently (i.e., no `SQLException`s) but that's fine.  More importantly, no changes are made to `t` and `t4` because of the failed lock on `t3` in `tr2`.  I attempted to  create a save-point just before locking but rolling back to that save-point in the catch clause also failed.  It would appear that failure to lock caused the transaction to be [uncommittable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx#Anchor_5).  Is there any way to recover from this while still retaining the changes made thus far?  Or, is there an alternative to `UPDLOCK` with `NOWAIT` that doesn't cause the transaction to be uncommitable?